# C Language Data Structure Visualisation

Tags: c, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

Are there any C-language static analysers out there that create graphical diagrams of the data structures in a body of C code?

I'm thinking along the lines of the data displays in the DDD (Data Display Debugger) but that work from static analysis of the source code.

Any diagram notation welcome (UML etc.) and it can run on any platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html). It is fairly inexpensive and does just this and comes with a 30 day free trial. And no, I don't work for them :) .

[Understand](http://www.scitools.com/index.php) is also a great tool for diagraming existing C / C++ code, to help you understand it.

Comment: Ohh, "Enterprise Architect".  Those two words together in the name of a product scare me :D

Comment: +1 for Understand.   A great tool for documenting structures and call trees.